# How to convert list of lists to dict key value pairs python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of lists like so:

```
splitted = [['OID:XXXXXXXXXXX1',
  ' street:THE ROAD',
  'town:NEVERPOOL',
  'postcode:M1 2DD',
  'Name:SOMEHWERE',
  'street:THE ROAD',
  'town:NEVERLAND',
  'postcode:M1 2DD'],
 ['OID:XXXXXXXXXXX2',
  ' Name:30',
  'street:DA PLACE',
  'town:PERTH',
  'postcode:PH1 2DD',
  'Name:30',
  'street:DA PLACE',
  'town:PERTH',
  'postcode:PH1 2DD']]
```

I'd like to convert these to key values pairs like so:

```
{'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX1', ' street': 'THE ROAD', 'town': 'NEVERPOOL', 'postcode': 'M1 2DD', 'Name': 'SOMEWHERE', 'street': 'THE ROAD', 'town': 'NEVERPOOL', 'postcode': 'M1 2DD'}, {'MPXN': 'XXXXXXXXXXX2', ' Name': '30', 'street': 'DA PLACE', 'town': 'PERTH', 'postcode': 'PH1 2DD', 'primaryName': '30', 'street1': 'DA PLACE', 'town': 'PERTH', 'postcode': 'PH1 2DD'}
```

I am unable to find a way online to convert a list of lists into key-value pairs as a dict to then be consumed by pandas. The purpose of this is to convert the dicts into a pandas DataFrame so I can then consume it and work with it in a tabular format

The code I have used thus far is here:

```
output = []
for list in splitted:
    for key_value in list:
        key, value = key_value.split(':', 1)
        if not output or key in output[0]:
            output.append({})
        output[-1][key] = value
```

The problem with the above code is that it does not maintain the list of lists and mixes up the OID field with other data items, I'd like a dict starting from each OID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you append a new dict to `output` *every time* that the first element of `output` has the `key` you're looking for. This causes your code to fail, because after the first `list in splitted` has been processed, the first element of `output` looks like this:

```
{'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX1',
  ' street': 'THE ROAD',
  'town': 'NEVERPOOL',
  'postcode': 'M1 2DD',
  'Name': 'SOMEHWERE',
  'street': 'THE ROAD'}
```

and all `key` values you will see henceforth already exist in said element.

What you actually want to do is to *add a new dict* every time you encounter a new `list in splitted`.

```
output = []
for l in splitted:
    output.append(dict())
    for key_value in l:
        key, value = key_value.split(':', 1)
        output[-1][key] = value
```

And now you get what you expected:

```
[{'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX1',
  ' street': 'THE ROAD',
  'town': 'NEVERLAND',
  'postcode': 'M1 2DD',
  'Name': 'SOMEHWERE',
  'street': 'THE ROAD'},
 {'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX2',
  ' Name': '30',
  'street': 'DA PLACE',
  'town': 'PERTH',
  'postcode': 'PH1 2DD',
  'Name': '30'}]
```

While I have your attention:

- `dict`s are an unordered data type in python (or ordered by insertion-order), so "mixes up the OID field with other data items" isn't really a thing. You wanted to create a *single dict* with all those keys, but you ended up creating a bunch of dicts, each with one key (after the first one)
- `list` is a built-in class in python, so creating a variable called `list` shadows this class. You shouldn't do this, because later you might encounter errors if you want to use the `list` class.
- Debugging is a crucial skill for a programmer to have. I encourage you to take a look at these links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
  |
  [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) You can use a debugger to step through your code and observe how each statement affects the state of your program, and this helps you figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and thank you for this feedback. It is noted

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is simplier:

```
splitted = [['OID:XXXXXXXXXXX1',
  ' street:THE ROAD',
  'town:NEVERPOOL',
  'postcode:M1 2DD',
  'Name:SOMEHWERE',
  'street:THE ROAD',
  'town:NEVERLAND',
  'postcode:M1 2DD'],
 ['OID:XXXXXXXXXXX2',
  ' Name:30',
  'street:DA PLACE',
  'town:PERTH',
  'postcode:PH1 2DD',
  'Name:30',
  'street:DA PLACE',
  'town:PERTH',
  'postcode:PH1 2DD']]

output = []
for i in range(len(splitted)):
    output.append(dict())
    for j in splitted[i]:
        k,v = j.split(':')
        output[i][k] = v
```

the output is:

```
[{'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX1',
  ' street': 'THE ROAD',
  'town': 'NEVERLAND',
  'postcode': 'M1 2DD',
  'Name': 'SOMEHWERE',
  'street': 'THE ROAD'},
 {'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX2',
  ' Name': '30',
  'street': 'DA PLACE',
  'town': 'PERTH',
  'postcode': 'PH1 2DD',
  'Name': '30'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to use dictionary comprehension:

```
[{x.split(":")[0]:x.split(":")[1] for x in splitted[0]},
 {x.split(":")[0]:x.split(":")[1] for x in splitted[1]}]
```

The output is:

```
[{'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX1', ' street': 'THE ROAD', 'town': 'NEVERLAND', 'postcode': 'M1 2DD', 'Name': 'SOMEHWERE', 'street': 'THE ROAD'}, {'OID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX2', ' Name': '30', 'street': 'DA PLACE', 'town': 'PERTH', 'postcode': 'PH1 2DD', 'Name': '30'}]
```